# Use PHP/ASP pages as middle men between sending data back and forth

Tags: php, asp.net, cross-platform

I am looking to write a system which allows for easy implementation and future development as well as can run on multiple platforms. The website system acts as a middle man. The idea is that it is a platform which can easy be tapped into by simply sending it tokens/query strings and receive data back, given appropriate authentication and what not. The old way of approaching this was Java/C++ socket programming because it could be cross compiled on many platforms. I want to stay away from writing a whole socket driven client/server system.

The idea is that you pass a PHP or ASP page a number of GET strings (or POST if possible) and it will give you back an XML file which holds the data you have requested. So for instance

```
  myPage.php?_auth=7ddf32e17a6ac5ce04a8ecbf782ca509&_REQUEST=BelgianWaffle
```

The issue at hand is that I have no idea if this is even possible with PHP/ASP.NET or if it is, where to start looking (Tried a few terms with google, didn't come up with anything).

I know twitter and facebook have similar systems so that remote website can post stuff remotely.

Comment: What are you asking?  If it's possible to build an ASP.NET (or did you actually mean _ASP_ as in ASP Classic?) or PHP application which can accept web requests, perform server-side actions, and respond with data?  Yes... It is possible.  So, what's your question?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all what language you use. Exactly what is the question?

Comment: Different languages have different limitations which I may or may not be aware of so I included both. I work in both ASP/PHP professionally and personally and have never had to do anything like this. Its a general question of "Can I write a remote application, Android, iOS, C#, Java, PHP, etc. and be able to obtain data from a webpage in the form of a passed back XML" I think the person who answered has the right idea. Ill make sure to better my wording next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible.  In fact, what you've described is basically a web service.  You could start here: [ASP.NET Web Services Tutorial](http://progtutorials.tripod.com/WebServices.htm)

Another tutorial in video: [[How Do I:] Create and Call a Simple Web Service in ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet)